# Proposed capitalisation fix

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

When you ask a question on main, you are greeted with the words *What's your christianity question? be specific*. I'd say that both *Christianity* and *be* should have initial capital letters.

Comment: Nice catch!  I agree...

Comment: Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2137/1696.

Answer (score 4):

"What's" isn't capitalized either, actually. Also, I looked on [MetaSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=capitalization) ([twice!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=capitalize&submit=search)) and there is oddly not a single question about this. You could raise it there if you want, but I find it telling that no one else has noticed *and* posted a Meta question about it. Personally, I noticed, but I didn't care about it as the lack of capitalization actually kinda emphasizes its non-obtrusive appearance.